# Configuration Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Tags: installation

Good afternoon,

I trying to install Magento on a vps server.
I can't find any instructions how configure the webserver.

I need to know what applications i need to install, such as apache, phpmyadmin, mysql etc.
I allso wanna know if "Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS 64-bit" is compatible with Magento!
If it's not i can choose another installation. My host provider offers different kind of installations

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For a [really]basic Magento installation follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide. 
You will need a LAMP environment for a this, but it can be improved by using Memcache, Redis, MariaDB, etc. Start by configuring the LAMP environment and once you are familiar with it continue with more advanced software.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as accepted @IvanDjakie!

Comment: Hi, its's not working.

Comment: That does not help at all. What did you tried, why do you think it did not work, any error you saw...

Comment: The guide is actually working for tons of other people, i suggest you to check again.

Comment: Yes i will start over again But i have one question. I can choose for a presintalled VPS Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS 64-bit and ISO VPS Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS 64-bit WIch one should i choose?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, you might have to ask your hosting provider about that.

Comment: I would choose a server with for example Plesk control panel. That way you can install Magento with one click and Apache / Nginx / MySql etc will already be pre-installed.